# Putting multiple lines of Python into ArcGIS 10's Field Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, python-parser, error-000539

Entering these lines of Python one at a time works like a charm... Just need one more seemingly simply issue solved...

How do we place **multiple** lines of Python code into ArcGIS's Field Calculator without producing **Error 000539 or syntax error**?

I've tried several different syntaxes with colons and various spacings / returns .... screen shot:

[image]   multiple lines of Python code here:

```
'1201-LT 210A' if !sc2! in (12013,11999,11998,12016,12015,12004,12012,12011,12001,12002,11997,12017,12009,12003) else !March_Proj!

'1201-LT 210B' if !sc2! in (12074,12076,12078,12072) else !March_Proj!

'1201-BO' if !sc2! in (20052,20053,20044,20045,20039,20050,20051,24157,24158,22927,24783,24785,24784,24782,24035,22924,23923,24154,22528,21912,23164) else !March_Proj!

'1202-LT 21F' if !sc2! in (1067,1066,1078,1060,1052,1075,1068,1051,1079,1062,1070,,1071) else !March_Proj!
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code you are using since it seems to fail on the first field in your table that contains a null value and seems to partially calculate values for the destination field that have values in the first field.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan. All of the code is here: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LbbcvSKYwfp9e_SG93ho5awUBl1siMiKXrCk7aedHeo/edit?hl=en&authkey=CLqlk8EN) If i enter the lines one by one and hit ok in Field Calculator they work fine.... just would like to do them all at once since i will being hundreds more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have ArcGIS 10 (yet), but from I read, you need to define a function:

```
def classify(value, default_value):
    if value in [14175,14161,14180,13459,13460,14652,14648,14647,14644]:
        return '1101A-BB 300B'
    elif value in [20077,20102,20106,20107,20165,20169,20170,20250,20263,20323,20327,20328,20462,20463,21871,24184,21167,21247,21248]:
        return '1101A-BO'
    elif value in [16708,16668,16669,16670,16698,16683,16700,16699,16709,16743,16742,16740,16739,16738,16706,16711,16701,16705,16713,16714,16693,16746]:
        return '1101A-LT_314'
    elif value in [21829]:
        return '1205-DFM DFDS362'
    # etc...
    else:
        return default_value
```

Then at the bottom (the next box), you would call the function:

```
classify(!sc2!, !March_Proj!)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, i just tried (twice) entering that code and arcmap goes into a some sort of a loop and has to be killed in task manager.... i tested it by simply deleting the `# etc...` and the ensuing empty line.
and leaving everything else alone...  is !March_Proj! highlighted in blue for any particular reason?

Comment: Ah, I had two syntax errors: I forgot the "`:`" at the end of two statements. They are fixed in the above, so you can test it out again. The `# etc...` is a harmless comment, and I'm not sure why gis.se's syntax highlighter is marking `!March_Proj!` with blue text, but it shouldn't make any difference in the end.

Comment: Mike, when i input the code you have listed above it works perfectly... somewhere when i populated the rest of it there's a glitch (beyond the 8 or so syntax errors i corrected from my imperfect copy / paste methods)... the error screen shot i keep getting here: [link](http://i.imgur.com/READv.jpg)  the entire code here: [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fUxaFStFsrlazyNKazhUk8KfukqXnCuSFWCNr_j031U/edit?hl=en&pli=1#) i am putting it all in pre-logic minus the end piece `classify(!sc2!, !March_Proj!)` which goes in the bottom.

Comment: You had a special case where you were comparing one item: `value in (21829)` is incorrect, but `value in (21829,)` is correct. The reason is that you are creating "tuples" on the right-hand side, and tuples can have a tricky syntax. A list could also work, which looks like `[21829]`. I've added this case example to the above code. You can debug the function directly in [PythonWin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) to find what line-number the error happens on.

Comment: Actually, I changed the example to use lists (rather than tuples), since the tuple exception is a silly distraction. Python lists are normally a lot more useful anyways.

Comment: This looks like it might work, i'll give it a go first thing in the morning... much thanks!

Comment: It works Mike! Really appreciate the help... not sure if i need to start another topic for one other question on this... I have many index xls files i am pulling this data from after running an Excel macro someone turned me on to at ExcelForum.com here: [link](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AkujPOzxeGqedDQ2YTRzMGVTX1VvalB4ZDdfeVdtTlE&hl=en#gid=0) Seems there should be find/replace reg exp to populate the pre-logic, yes?  i am able to do a bunch of manual copy/paste and find/replace but if you know a simple reg exp or where i could look to build it, that would make it more automated.